# Which version of Drush should I install?

Tags: drush

Drush 6 works great of corse on a Drupal 6 website, but will I have all of the Drush 6 features when working on a Drupal 7 website? Should I use Drush 7 when working on a drupal 7 website?

I found this post that says you can switch between the two version easily, is this correct?

switch to drush6 command:
composer global require drush/drush:6.*

switch to drush7 command:
composer global require drush/drush:dev-master

Comment: Well, you shouldn't be working on Drupal 6 since it's no longer supported **"On February 24th 2016, Drupal 6 will reach end of life and no longer be supported."** Unless you're in the processing of upgrading. More info at [Drupal 6 end-of-life announcement](https://www.drupal.org/drupal-6-eol)

Answer (score 9):

Always, always read the docs. Right at the bottom of [the first page](https://www.drush.org/latest/install/#drupal-compatibility) you'll find this:

[image: Drush compatibility chart]

Which removes any ambiguity.

Comment: It's worth noting that the PHP requirements for Drush are higher than those for Drupal 6 and 7 core.   This may or may not be an issue; check your server config.  It is also worth noting that all of those PHP versions are pretty ancient; all of the ones listed in the table above are EOL.

Comment: Drush 9 will require PHP 5.5. Drush supports ancient versions of PHP to help interoperability with old servers on LTS distributions, but it's always advisable to upgrade when possible, even when the old versions are still functional.